# Fatal error: Class 'JLanguage' not found joomla 1.5

Tags: php, joomla

Fatal error: Class 'JLanguage' not found in /includes/application.php on line 68

code:

```
// One last check to make sure we have something
        if ( ! JLanguage::exists($options['language']) ) {
            $options['language'] = 'en-GB';
        }

        parent::initialise($options);
```

Please help me..

thanks all

Comment: Are you sure you have included JLanguage in your file ?

Comment: You have some core files missing. Reupload and reinstall the website.

Comment: come on man put your some effort to upgrade the Joomla instead of fixing the outdated code.

Comment: Thank you everyone, i have updated the new version and have been resolved

Answer (score 0):

You must have changed servers ...
There are some cases ...
Install the PHP modules.

And do a Joomla update via SSH or FTP.

Don't forget Backup before and after!

That solved for me ...

Success!!!

Answer (score 0):

Usually happens when you switch servers ...
Or switched from Database, a typical example is from Mysql to MariaDB.
There are some cases ...
Install the PHP modules.
Update your Joomla

Make sure your configuration.php is MYSQLi and change to PDOMYSQL

Success!!!